# How can i get animation of matrix transformations like this

Tags: linear-transformations

I found these transformations in Khan Academy and I don't know how they created the transformation example videos! I want to create transformations in this way.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/linear-transformations/a/visualizing-linear-transformations

Comment: I can't answer your question, but their videos look strikingly similar to ThreeBlueOneBrown's videos... Check it out https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they used 3Blue1Brown's manim library. Documentation is scarce but it is [available here on github](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/)